# Rails5 How can I build a feed with ActiveRecord Relation objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I'd like to build a feed with Microposts:

First I collect all Microposts from my following with `visible_for 'following'`

```
following_ids_subselect = "SELECT followed_id FROM relationships
                           WHERE  follower_id = :user_id"
following_feed = Micropost.where("visible_for = 'following' 
                                   AND user_id IN (#{following_ids_subselect})", user_id: id)
```

Then I collect all Microposts from my following (AND status "contact") with `visible_for 'contact'`

```
contacts_ids_subselect = "SELECT followed_id FROM relationships
                          WHERE  follower_id = :user_id
                          AND status = 'contact'"
contacts_feed = Micropost.where("visible_for = 'contacts' 
                                   AND user_id IN (#{contacts_ids_subselect})", user_id: id)
```

Is there any way to get `following_feed` and `contacts_feed` together? that I can write:

```
@feed_items = global_feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
```

In other words: 
`global_feed` should contain all Microposts from users the current user follows with `visible_for 'followers'`
+ 
all Microposts from users the curent user follows with `status 'contact'`  with `visible_for 'contacts'`

Update:

Relationship

```
class Relationship < ApplicationRecord
# Table name: relationships
#
#  id           :integer(4)      not null, primary key
#  follower_id  :integer(4)
#  followed_id  :integer(4)
#  status       :string        

  belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :followed, class_name: "User"
end
```

User

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :active_relationships, class_name:  "Relationship",
                              foreign_key: "follower_id",
                              dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :following, through: :active_relationships, source: :followed
  has_many :passive_relationships, class_name:  "Relationship",
                               foreign_key: "followed_id",
                               dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :followers, through: :passive_relationships, source: :follower
  (..)
end
```

Micropost

```
class Micropost < ApplicationRecord
#
# Table name: microposts
#
#  id          :integer(4)      not null, primary key
#  user_id     :integer(4)
#  content     :string
#  visible_for :string   

  belongs_to :user
  default_scope -> { order('created_at DESC') }     
end
```

Comment: I think there is a typo in the first snippet of code: `contact_ids_subselect` in the las SQL query should be `following_ids_subselect`?

Comment: What is `.paginate` method? Can it be applied to enumarble objects?

Comment: NickGnd you were right, I've corrected it. Paginate expects an active record object. Arrays for example cannot be applied (as far as I know)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#paginate` is a method only available on ActiveRecord relations. Which means you will need to select the data you need in one query.

So if I'm reading your sample correctly, you want all `Micropost`s from users the current user follows that are visible for `contacts` or `following`.

You can select them in one query like so

```
following_user_ids = user.following.pluck(:id)
contact_user_ids = Relationship.where(status: "contact", follower_id: user.id).pluck(:follower_id)

Microposts.where("(visible_for = 'followers' and user_id in (?)) OR (visible_for = "contacts" and user_id in (?)"), following_user_ids, contact_user_ids))
```

Comment: gives me `undefined method 'followeds' for 1:Fixnum.` When I try `.where(user_id: user.following.pluck(:id))` I get `undefined method 'following' for 1:Fixnum`

Comment: I want all Microposts from users the current user follows with `visible_for 'followers'` + all Microposts from users the curent user follows with `status 'contact'` with `visible_for 'contacts'`

Comment: Ah that's probably because you have an integer and not a user object. `User.find(user_id).followeds.pluck(:id)`

Comment: ok but that returns me also microposts from users the current user follows without `status 'contact'` and `visible_for 'contacts`

Comment: the query actually doesn't differ between microposts from relationsships and microposts from relationships with `status 'contact'`. The query shouldn't contain microposts from users the current user follows with `visible_for 'contacts'`. It should contain (a) microposts from users the current user follows with `visible_for 'follower'`and (b) microposts from users the current user follows with `status 'contact'` with `visible_for 'contacts'`